# Where to download a dictionary of medical terms

Tags: data-request, medical, dictionary

Can anyone recommend a place to download a dictionary of medical terms in XML or other suitable data format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Merriam-Webster's Medical Dictionary with Audio

Free for noncommercial (which here means *not generating any revenue*) use provided you submit less than 1000 queries a day. Other forms of licensing are available upon request.

[description](http://www.dictionaryapi.com/products/api-medical-dictionary.htm), [licencing and fees](http://www.dictionaryapi.com/info/frequently-asked-questions.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The CDC offers lots of codes for download:

https://www.cms.gov/Medicare/Coding/ICD9ProviderDiagnosticCodes/codes.html